# Is it possible to use some auth credentials of travis-ci or my user to use github api

Tags: travis-ci

for Testing on Travis-CI I need to download some projects from github by wget. Here is what I have in travis logs:

```
 Requesting a tar: 'wget https://api.github.com/repos/apache/hbase/tarball/1.1.0.1 -O src/main/java/apache-hbase.tar.gz'
 --2015-06-28 18:24:16-- https://api.github.com/repos/apache/hbase/tarball/1.1.0.1
 Resolving api.github.com (api.github.com)... 192.30.252.139
 Connecting to api.github.com (api.github.com)|192.30.252.139|:443... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
 2015-06-28 18:24:16 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Github support explained that as:

> You're probably hitting the rate limit for unauthenticated requests:
>   https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting
>
> If you switch to making authenticated requests -- you should get a
>   much better API rate limit. We don't provide support for the Travis
>   platform, so you should reach out to Travis support to understand the
>   options for making authenticated requests using their platform.

So questions is: is it possible to safely reuse Travis-CI credentials or credentials of my travis user to work with github api without limitations of 60 request per hour?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a [Github OAuth token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/) by storing it securely in an [encrypted variable](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypted-Variables) in Travis CI and then passing it to your `wget` call like this:

```
// First encrypt your Github OAuth token
travis encrypt MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN=token --add
```

The previous call will automatically add the environment variable hash to your `.travis.yml` file.

Then you should be able to use it like this in your `wget` call:

```
wget \
--header='Authorization: token $MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN' \
https://api.github.com/repos/apache/hbase/tarball/1.1.0.1 \
-O src/main/java/apache-hbase.tar.gz
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: My opensource project use FREE plan of travis, so we do not have dedicated server, I also use "sudo: false" that also limits a bit. "Encrypted variables are not added to untrusted builds such as pull requests coming from another repository." - that does not work for us, I need that Travis builds to check PRs from contributors.
Do you have any other ideas ?